# perl command runs indefinitely

Tags: perl, wildcard, unlink

I have a part of a perl script as:

```
my @filenames  = ("${home_dir}${month}_???_???.OUT",
                  "${home_dir}${month}_???_???.DAt");

   foreach my $list (@filenames) {
   unlink $list or warn "failed on $list: $!\n";
   }


  map { unlink(glob($_)) } @filenames;
```

in either way, to delete the files from the home director using either "unlink $list"  command  or global delete command " map { unlink(glob($_)) }" the command runs indefinitely.

It seems to me that "$list" does not find the files since it might not properly interpret the wildcard symbols (???_???)

any comments please ?

Comment: Did you try putting a `print` statement in the loop to see what it's doing?

Comment: just `unlink(@filenames);` or `unlink(map glob, @filenames);` you don't have to loop over files.

Comment: Hi Jim, when I put a print statement in the loop, like "print $list" it lists the file without interpreting the wild cards "_???_???" I expect it to list every file that satisfy the wild cards.

Comment: Hi Mpapec, thank you very much for your response. I did try as you have suggested but it still runs indefinitely

Comment: Perl isn't shell and does not do automatic expansion of wildcards. You have to use `glob()`.

Comment: Hi Slaven, I did that but with no avail. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

As a nice onliner:

`unlink glob("${home_dir}/${month}_???_???.{OUT,DAT}");`